# To change the background color of only a particular button out of multiple buttons in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have made a game that has 50 buttons. You have three tries to click on a button. If you clicked the correct one, that is the 25th one you win the game!. I want the only the button no.25 background color to change on click . How to do that. My program changes the color of all the buttons when the 25th button is clicked.

```
 <html ng-app="Bluebox">

 <head>
   <title>BlueBox</title>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <style>
     .red{
         background-color:brown;
     }
   </style>
   </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="BoxController">

        <strong  ng-repeat="x in boxes track by $index">
                <button ng-style="{'color':x.color}" ng-class="bgcolor" ng-
    click="pressed($index)" type="button">
                    Button {{x.Id}}
          </button>
        </strong>

  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module("Bluebox",[])
           .controller("BoxController",
    ["$scope","$log",function($scope,$log){


             var limit = 50;
  var arr = []; // populate in your controller
  for (var index = 0; index <= limit; index++) {


    arr.push({
     "color":"green",
      "Id": index
      })
   }


  $scope.boxes = arr;
  $scope.tries=3;

  $scope.pressed = function(index){

    if($scope.tries<=3 & $scope.tries!=0){
    $log.log("Button "+(index)+" was pressed");
   $scope.tries=$scope.tries-1;

    if(index==25){

        $scope.bgcolor="red";
        $log.log("you won the game");
        $scope.tries=0;
    }

    if($scope.tries==0 && index!=25){
        $log.log("you lost the game");
     }

     }

     else{
         $log.log("Please restart the game");
     }
    }

    }])
  </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add class `bgcolor` to only 25th button and set `win` flag like `ng-class="{bgcolor: ($index==24 && win)}"` so it will solved your issue.

```
if (index == 25) {
          $scope.win = true;
```

Currently you are adding `bgcolor` to all button which is wrong.

```js
angular.module("Bluebox", [])
  .controller("BoxController", ["$scope", "$log", function($scope, $log) {


    var limit = 50;
    var arr = []; // populate in your controller
    for (var index = 0; index <= limit; index++) {


      arr.push({
        "color": "green",
        "Id": index
      })
    }


    $scope.boxes = arr;
    $scope.tries = 3;
    $scope.win = false;


    $scope.pressed = function(index, event) {

      if ($scope.tries <= 3 & $scope.tries != 0) {
        $log.log("Button " + (index) + " was pressed");
        $scope.tries = $scope.tries - 1;

        if (index == 25) {
          $scope.win = true;
          $scope.bgcolor = "red";
          $log.log("you won the game");
          $scope.tries = 0;
          angular.element(event.currentTarget).addClass('red')
        }

        if ($scope.tries == 0 && index != 25) {
          $log.log("you lost the game");
        }

      } else {
        $log.log("Please restart the game");
      }
    }

  }])
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="Bluebox">

<head>
  <title>BlueBox</title>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="BoxController">

    <strong ng-repeat="x in boxes track by $index">
         <button ng-style="{'color':x.color}" ng-class="{bgcolor: ($index == 24 && win)}"
        
         ng-click="pressed($index, $event)"   type="button">
                        Button {{x.Id}}
              </button>
            </strong>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
 <strong  ng-repeat="x in boxes track by $index">
     <button ng-style="{'color':x.color}" ng-class="{bgcolor: $index==24}" ng-click="pressed($index)" type="button"> Button {{x.Id}}
     </button>
 </strong>
```

Comment: @java_jazz try click on 24th, here index is 0 based so  ng-click="pressed($index)"` will be 24 for 25th button

Comment: `if(index==24)` this should be correct condition in your controller.

Comment: @java_jazz I've updated my answer above with working code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how I would have done it. You can just catch the clicked `event` and add `style/class` to that particular clicked element.

I like `JS` so this can be achieved in the same fashion.

`angular.element()` lets you select the element on your DOM and you can pass any reference to `angular.element(reference)` to select the DOM element. For example `event.currentTarget` in this case gives you the reference of clicked element and you can use traditional `JS/Jquery` on it to do other things.

Hope this helps

Thanks

```js
angular.module("Bluebox",[])
           .controller("BoxController",
    ["$scope","$log","$timeout",function($scope,$log,$timeout){


             var limit = 50;
  var arr = []; // populate in your controller
  for (var index = 0; index <= limit; index++) {


    arr.push({
     "color":"green",
      "Id": index
      })
   }

 
  $scope.boxes = arr;
  $scope.tries=3;
  
  $scope.won = false;
  $scope.pressed = function(index,event){

    if($scope.tries<=3 & $scope.tries!=0){
    $log.log("Button "+(index)+" was pressed");
   $scope.tries=$scope.tries-1;
   
    if(index==25){

        $scope.bgcolor="red";
        $log.log("you won the game");
        $scope.tries=0;
        $scope.won = true;
        angular.element(event.currentTarget).addClass('red')
    }

    if($scope.tries==0 && index!=25){
        $log.log("you lost the game");
     }

     }

     else{
         $log.log("Please restart the game");
     }
    }

    }])
```

```css
.red{
         background-color:brown;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="Bluebox" ng-cloak>

 <head>
   <title>BlueBox</title>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>

   </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="BoxController">

    <strong  ng-repeat="x in boxes track by $index">
     <button ng-style="{'color':x.color}" 
    
     ng-click="pressed($index, $event)"   type="button">
                    Button {{x.Id}}
          </button>
        </strong>
 
 <h1 ng-show="won">You won</h1>
  </div>
 
 

  
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: check my updated answer. please upvote and accept if this resolved your query. Thanks :)